# How to draw a graphical count table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with two columns `customer1` and `customer2` which are string valued.  I would like to make a square graphical representation of the count  number for each pair from those two columns.

I  can do

```
df[['customer1', 'customer2']].value_counts()
```

which will give me the counts.  But how can I make something that looks a little like:

[image]

from the result?

I can't provide my real dataset  but here is a toy example with three labels in csv.

```
customer1,customer2
a,b
a,c
a,c
b,a
b,c
b,c
c,c
a,a
b,c
b,c
```

Comment: Look at [seaborn.heatmap](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html)...

Comment: @MaxU That looks good. Do you know how to go from a pandas data frame to something that sns.heatmap can accept?

Comment: please provide a sample data set

Comment: @MaxU I can't provide the real data sadly but I just added a toy example in csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> Is it possible to sort the rows/columns so the highest count rows are
>   at the top ? In this case the order would be b,a,c

IIUC you can do it this way (where ):

```
In [80]: x = df.pivot_table(index='customer1',columns='customer2',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)

In [81]: idx = x.max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=0).index

In [82]: idx
Out[82]: Index(['b', 'a', 'c'], dtype='object', name='customer1')

In [87]: sns.heatmap(x[idx].reindex(idx), annot=True)
Out[87]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x9ee3f98>
```

[image]

**OLD answer:**

you can use [heatmap()](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) method from `seaborn` module:

```
In [42]: import seaborn as sns

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
  customer1 customer2
0         a         b
1         a         c
2         a         c
3         b         a
4         b         c
5         b         c
6         c         c
7         a         a
8         b         c
9         b         c

In [44]: x = df.pivot_table(index='customer1',columns='customer2',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)

In [45]: x
Out[45]:
customer2  a  b  c
customer1
a          1  1  2
b          1  0  4
c          0  0  1

In [46]: sns.heatmap(x)
Out[46]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xb150b70>
```

[image]

or with annotations:

```
In [48]: sns.heatmap(x, annot=True)
Out[48]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc596d68>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to sort the rows/columns so the highest count rows are at the top ? In this case the order would be b,a,c.

Comment: @eleanora, please check UPDATE section

Comment: Thank you for the update. I meant that the rows and columns get sorted the same way. So in this case the rows would be b,a,c and so would the columns.

Comment: I added a follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291261/how-to-draw-a-heatmap-in-pandas-with-items-that-dont-occur-in-both-columns .

Answer (score 0):

As @MaxU mentioned, `seaborn.heatmap` should work. It appears that you can use the Pandas DataFrame as the input.

`seaborn.heatmap(data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, center=None, robust=False, annot=None, fmt='.2g', annot_kws=None, linewidths=0, linecolor='white', cbar=True, cbar_kws=None, cbar_ax=None, square=False, ax=None, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, mask=None, **kwargs)`

https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap

Comment: The data frame would have to hold the count data I assume so we still need to compute that?