# How to draw a heatmap in pandas with items that don't occur in both columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

In [How to draw a graphical count table in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279858/how-to-draw-a-graphical-count-table-in-pandas) I asked how to draw a heatmap from input data such as:

```
customer1,customer2
a,b
a,c
a,c
b,a
b,c
b,c
c,c
a,a
b,c
b,c
```

The answer was

```
x = df.pivot_table(index='customer1',columns='customer2',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
idx = x.max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=0).index
sns.heatmap(x[idx].reindex(idx), annot=True)
```

This gives a square matrix showing the number of counts for each pair from the two columns.

This solution doesn't work however if there items in the first column which don't appear in the second. For example:

```
a,b
a,c
c,b
```

Gives an error saying that [u,'a'] is not in the Index.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: can you provide a sample data set which would help to reproduce your problem?

Comment: It's the three line one at the bottom of the question.

Comment: OK, what would be the desired __sorted__ DF which you want to represent as a heatmap?

Comment: @MaxU In the small example in  the question the row order would be a,c and the column order would be a,c,b.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [129]: df
Out[129]:
  customer1 customer2
0         a         b
1         a         c
2         a         c
3         b         b
4         b         c
5         b         c
6         c         c
7         a         b
8         b         c
9         b         c

In [130]: x = df.pivot_table(index='customer1',columns='customer2',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)

In [131]: idx = x.max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=0).index

In [132]: cols = x.max().sort_values(ascending=0).index

In [133]: sns.heatmap(x[cols].reindex(idx), annot=True)
Out[133]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xbb22588>
```

[image]

Comment: In this example we need to make the column order b,a,c as in the row order. That means we will end up with a blank column.